# C++ Char - Relational Operators

Tags: c++, if-statement, char, comparison, operators

I have a little problem working on with char in C++ as I have tried comparing 2 texts in an if and there is what I've got:

**Input:**

```
if ( "bac" < "ab" ) cout<<"1";
if ( "ab" > "bac" ) cout<<"1";
```

**Output :**

```
11
```

I don't really understand why it is printing "11", but moreover if I erase the first 'if' it will no longer print anything on the screen. Could you please explain why it has such a behaviour on these IFs?

Comment: You are comparing pointers, not characters.

Comment: There are probably several duplicates on SO on this subject. The problem is that those expressions compare pointers, not strings. To compare strings, use `if ( std::string("abd") < std::string("ab") )`.

Comment: @RSahu I think this is an occasion where `strcmp` might usefully be used, rather than converting things to std::string.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, if performance is not an issue, I would go with the more idiomatic way -- using `std::string`s. If peformance is an issue, I would go with your suggestion.

Comment: Could you detail more about pointers comparison in this case and how could I make it to work right?

Comment: Those conditions are equivalent, so if one is true, the other will be too.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, of course, that's what I have thought as well, but when I tried deleting the first condition and running the program just with this "if ( "ab" > "bac" ) cout<<"1";" it no longer prints anything on the screen. And that was some interesting and strange thing to me, so I thought it must be something that I don't seem to figure out about how this comparison is working.

Comment: @RSahu I don't see your solution as being "more idiomatic" if the program is dealing with pointer to char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
`if("abc" < "bcd" );
```

This is equivalent to:

```
char* a= "abc";
char* b ="bcd";
if( a < b );
```

`a` and `b` are pointers, addresses in memory. So no matter what are in the two strings, they are in different places in memory. That means no matter what the content of the two strings, `a` will never be *equal* to `b`.

When you `"abc"` you get the memory location of that string. So that is what is meant by, "*You are comparing pointers.*"; C++ is not like other languages where the *machine* is abstracted away. You are working with the real one's and zero's that the machine uses. And everything lives somewhere in memory.

`strcmp` is a function that take two pointers then compares the values in the memory location that those pointers refer to.

```
if( ! strcmp(a,b) )
   ;//then the two strings are the same
```

Comment: Useful stuff to know about pointers comparison. Many thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing pointers, not characters.

If you're using a modern compiler you can do it like this instead:

```
if ("bac"s < "ab"s) cout << "1";
if ("ab"s > "bac"s) cout << "1";
```

The `s` suffix tells the compiler that the string literals are of type `std::string`.

---

If your compiler doesn't support that, you can do it the old fashioned way:

```
if (string("bac") < string("ab")) cout << "1";
if (string("ab") > string("bac")) cout << "1";
```

---

Or the ancient C-style way:

```
if (strcmp("bac, "ab") < 0) cout << "1";
if (strcmp("ab, "bac") > 0) cout << "1";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :)